# How to make a block of codes as pseudocode all at once in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

i.e. Are there any shortcuts that can prefix multiple lines of codes with an "#" in one setting?

Answer (score 1):

If by pseudocode you mean code comments, you can select the entire code block with the mouse and press CTRL+K+C.
Otherwise, you need to find an extension to convert your code to pseudocode.